# css doesn't see element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with submit button (id="submit") and `<style>` in `<head>` doesn't see this button.
I have style like this:

```
  #submit {
        display: block;
        margin: 70px auto;
    }
```

The element is like this:

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="submit">Create</button>
```

But the styling doesn't work, and Firefox Firebug doesn't see my styling AT ALL, even if i change it to `button#submit` or `button.btn-primary`.
I have no idea why it doesn't work. Does enyone know what to do?

Comment: your code is working, you might have some divs not closing properly, check your markup carefully.

Comment: or paste whole code

Comment: your code is ok check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shall_jsfiddle/2wjor5r2/)... show us your markup

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If not possible to show your code you can share screenshot of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works.here it is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #submit {
            display: block;
            margin: 70px auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="submit">Create</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```